# SQL Get first row of each unique ID AND each row with that ID within x time after the first

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to have a single SQL command that returns each unique userID from a table as well as the rows containing that userID within the next 24 hours.

So for example I may have a table structured like:

```
id | userID | action | date
```

with a bunch of rows with thousands of unique userIDs, dozens of different actions, and dates.  I am basically interested in what actions each userID does within the first 24 hours, but this for all users.

So I should get maybe 10-15 different actions for each userID, and each userID will be signing up on different days, months, or even years so it's not just grabbing all actions over a specific 24 hour period.

Comment: So it's 24 hours after each user's first action?

Comment: 24 hours from their first record, or last record?

Comment: 24 hours from each userID's first record

Comment: are you looking fro something like `cron job`? if so see  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5, and some tutos http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml, or http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: thanks, but I don't need a cron job.  I have an already created large set of data that I want to go through and just pull out the first 24 hours worth of rows for each ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM
  actions a1 INNER JOIN (SELECT   userID, MIN(date) first_action
                         FROM     actions
                         GROUP BY userID) a2
  ON a1.userID = a2.userID AND a1.date <= first_action + INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e060/1). This query will return all actions that each user does in the first 24 hours after their first action.

Comment: thanks, this is perfect! (and also thanks for introducing me to sqlfiddle)